# I hear people say names at the end of the sentence, to identify who they are speaking about

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering what culture in the U.S. or what region of the U.S. has this language style.

"He just threw a left hook, John."

(John is who threw the left hook.)  Who puts it as first described?

Comment: I suggest you add another quote mark. At the moment it is not clear where your (or if your) quote ends.

Comment: This is called "right dislocation". Here is a question asking about its use in British varieties of English: “[Knows an awful lot about the Dark Arts, Snape”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209235). There is more information about this construction in the following posts: [Is it grammatically correct to shift an appositive away from the noun it renames or describes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300649), [Why does the following phrase sound old fashioned?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167255)

Comment: @sumelic The *Snape* quote works, but the OP's version has a "he" at the start as well as a "John" at the end. That doesn't sound like an assertion that John threw the left hook. It sounds more like someone addressing John, saying that someone else (*he*) threw the left hook.